# JPA @MapsID getting error org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data-jpa

**User:**

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user")
    private Address address;


    //Getters and setters
}
```

**Address:**

```
@Entity
public class Address {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String country;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    @MapsId
    private User user;


    //Getters and setters
}
```

**Below is the error I am getting:**

```
2020-05-02 02:33:42 - Uncaught Runtime Exception
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance
```

User and Address classes both share the same Primary key..

**Could you please tell me what still I have to change in my above code? I have written above based on some example I found, I will be glad if someone could explain me whats happening internally**

**EDIT:**

I am trying to insert **User**  having RequestBody as **below**, then facing above exception.

```
{
    "name": "john",
    "adddress": {
        "country": "US"
    }
}
```

Comment: can anyone pls look into above

Comment: Can you provide the code where the exception occurs?

Comment: @MinarMahmud I just edited my query, please find above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cascade the relationship. In `User` entity, change the relationship to:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
```

This will propagate any operation from parent to child entity, ie, from `User` to `Address` here. So, when you will persist an `User` object, associated `Address` object will be persisted as well and so on.

#### Further Reading:

- [**`CascadeType`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/index.html?javax/persistence/CascadeType.html) in javadoc
- [***Cascading entity state transitions***](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc-cascade) in Hibernate User Guide

Comment: After I gave above cascadeType, I am getting another error now:   org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property [Address.user]; nested exception is org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property [Address.user]

Comment: Can you please post the codes where you initializing and persisting?

Comment: I am using Spring Data JPA (ie., my DAO interfaces just extends CrudRepository). Is that possible for you to provide me working code having @OneToOne MapsId ?

Comment: In Controller, all I have is userRepository.save(user), thats it!

Comment: Well I'm not sure if yours is the proper use case of `@MapsId`. See this link from hibernate guide with example codes 
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-derived

Comment: Hmm.. Thats okay, I will look into above one later. Atleast do you aware for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61561728/how-to-store-multivaluemap-in-mysql-using-jpa-hibernate

Answer (score 0):

You need to make 2 modifications:

- add cascade `@OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)`
- make sure that both:

  - address points to user
  - user points to address

The latter is typically accomplished via a custom setter, that sets both sides of the relationship

```
public void setAddress(Address address) {
    if (address == null) {
        if (this.address != null) {
            this.address.setUser(null);
        }
    }
    else {
        address.setUser(this);
    }
    this.details = details;
}
```

Please check that this is called when deserializing JSON to your entities.