# How to Store MultivalueMap in MySQL using JPA/Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am very new to JPA/Hibernate. In my app, I am using Spring Data JPA. I have a requirement to store MultivalueMap in Mysql DB. I have found examples only based on Map, but not MultiValueMap.

**At first, is that possible to store MultiValueMap in MySQL DB?**

**Second, I will be glad, if someone show me some good example on above.**

Comment: It depends on how you want to store it. Think MultiValueMap  as Map<K, List<V>>

Comment: @Eklavya I knew what is MultiValueMap , but I am not understanding how to write HIbnernate code to store that in DB, any example or sample code would be helpful for me.

Comment: I post an example

Answer (score 1):

You can store `Map<K, List<V>>` as `Set<Map.Entry<K, List<V>>>` this way.

```
@Entity
public class Entity {
    //...
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "entity_id")
    private Set<MultiValueMapEntry> multiValueMap = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Entity
public class MultiValueMapEntry {
    private String key;

    @ElementCollection
    private List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

In Entity class use @OneToMany Unidirectional relation for every `Map.Entry<K, List<V>>`
and use `@ElementCollection` for `List<V>` of every map entry.

To learn about @OneToMany Unidirectional see [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) and 
to learn about @ElementCollection see [here](https://thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-tips-elementcollection/)

And for `Set<Map.Entry<K, List<V>>>` to `Map<K, List<V>>` converstion see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16108734/convert-setmap-entryk-v-to-hashmapk-v)

Comment: Did you try this solution ?